# how do i push a specific element at the last of the list in an existing list in python 3.7.2

Tags: python

```
l1 = [1,2,0,3,4,0,5,6,0,8,9,0]
```

expected output as below

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I have solution for this above query , so wanted to know if there are any other solutions for the same?

```
for i in l1:
    if i == 0:
        l1.remove(0)
        l1.append(0)


>>> l1

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>>
```

Comment: Try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . If you have a working solution and want to improve, it is a better address.

Comment: It's not clear from this one sample what you need - move all elements with a specific value to the end of the list?

Comment: i mean to say i can pick any one element of my choice and that element should be appended at end of the list. for ex in my example i selected as of now as 0

Answer (score 0):

I would *cheat* my way around it:

```
l1 = [1,2,0,3,4,0,5,6,0,8,9,0]

res = list(filter(None, l1)) + [0] * l1.count(0)
print(res)  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

---

So fist you just filter out the `0`s and finally you extend the created list by as many `0`s as were initially there.

Answer (score 0):

here are several examples:

**1)**

```
l1 = [1,2,0,3,4,0,5,6,0,8,9,0]
def nonzero(a):
    """Return a copy of the iterable a with all zeros at the end."""
    return sorted(a, key=lambda x: x == 0)
print (nonzero(l1))
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

**2)**

```
l1 = [1,2,0,3,4,0,5,6,0,8,9,0]
result =[nonZero for nonZero in l1 if nonZero != 0] + [Zero for Zero in l1 if Zero == 0]
print(result)
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

**3)**

```
l1 = [1,2,0,3,4,0,5,6,0,8,9,0]
def nonzero(lst):
  n = len(lst)
  lst[:] = filter(None, lst)
  lst.extend([0] * (n - len(lst)))
  return lst
print (nonzero(l1))
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

**4)**

```
l1 = [1,2,0,3,4,0,5,6,0,8,9,0]
def nonzero(a):
  zeros = [0] * a.count(0)
  x = [ i for i in a if i != 0]
  x.extend(zeros)
  return(x)
print (nonzero(l1))
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```